# Cannot run application after adding Geolocator package

Tags: flutter, dart, latitude-longitude

I am trying to use Geolocator in my Flutter project. I have put the latest package in the pubspec.yaml and also put the permission to access user location in AndroidManifest.xml

And I try to get the user location by:

```
void getLocation() async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
}
```

But I am not able to run the application. Below is the error produced. Does anyone have any idea on this?

[image]

Below is the app\build.gradle
[image]

Comment: set  compileSdkVersion 30 in gradle file

Comment: @Balaji already set the compileSdkVersion to 30 before running the app